# Go to payment option directly if user is logged in in onepagecheckout

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I am trying to override the **onepage checkout** controllers in way that if the user is logged in he should directly go to the **payment options** and will not see the **billing details**.

The approach I am using is that I'm trying to override the `/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php` file and edit the `indexAction()` method to achieve this. But I see that I cannot do that until each step is **posted its data**. I have modified the `indexAction()` method in the following way uptil now,

```
public function indexAction()
{
    if (!Mage::helper('checkout')->canOnepageCheckout()) {
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($this->__('The onepage checkout is disabled.'));
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }
    $quote = $this->getOnepage()->getQuote();
    if (!$quote->hasItems() || $quote->getHasError()) {
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }
    if (!$quote->validateMinimumAmount()) {
        $error = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/error_message') ?
            Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/error_message') :
            Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Subtotal must exceed minimum order amount');

        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($error);
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(false);
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_secure' => true)));

    // Save the billing and shipping sections
    // And then proceed to payment section
    if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
        $this->saveBillingAction();
        $this->saveShippingAction();


    }

    $this->getOnepage()->initCheckout();
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Checkout'));
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento uses javascript in order to deal with one step checkout steps. So instead of dealing with the controller file, you need to overwrite the default js file that deals with one step checkout.

You can find the file here

> skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js

What you need to do is, after the DOM loaded you need to trigger billing method step with a default billing address, shipping step needs to trigger with the default shipping address and shipping method should trigger with a default shipping method.

All these above steps you need to do via js and use your custom js along with default `opcheckout.js` or completely avoiding it.

Either way, it would be a lengthy process. Wishing you the best :)